# Is this possible to the table view can scroll the position to Bottom or not?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use this function to call the UITableView scroll:

```
    UITableViewScrollPosition position = UITableViewScrollPositionBottom;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                            atScrollPosition:position
                                    animated:YES];
```

It is success if the top have enough cell, like this:

[image]

But if this is not success, for example, the A Cell, it is the first one, so that it can't scroll to Bottom, it will work like this:

[image]

Can I detect which cell can be scroll to Bottom and which can't ? Thanks.

Comment: you should try `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` instead of `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom`.

Comment: But still have A cannot scroll to Middle as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by manipulating the `tableView.contentInset` property. You will need to check the number of rows and do the manipulations accordingly.

Hope this helps.